# Titles that ask "X on Y"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Titles that ask "X on Y", are they permitted? Two recent examples:

[Nietzsche on the idea of Alienation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/nietzsche-on-the-idea-of-alienation)

and

[Quine on higher set theory](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41991/quine-on-higher-set-theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the question does not have to be a question itself. The only requirement is that it clearly and specifically describes the topic of the question. If the question can be summarised in one sentence, that is usually a good title. When the question is "What does Nietzsche say about alienation?", I don't see the problem with the title "Nietzsche on the idea of alienation".

Some examples of **good** titles:

- [What is the fallacy in comparing evolution to a fairy tale?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2990/2953)
- [Was Socrates a fictional character invented by Plato?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2484/2953)
- [What is 'intuition' for Kant?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/41579/2953)

Some examples of **bad** titles:

- What fallacy is this? — *'this' refers to the body, so this is not descriptive*
- Plato and Socrates — *the body provides necessary context*
- Philosophy of mind: what is 'intuition' for Kant? — *'Philosophy of mind' is a tag and can be omitted from the title - however, for tags like 'kant', they usually appear naturally in the title*

Comment: thanks keelan, and example of a good answer :-) ! what about "X on Y" which isn't so broad as the question title would suggest ?